# What is the right daytime format for plotting time series in python for a big dataset?

Tags: python, time-series, forecasting

I am trying to plot a time series for my dataset which has 215 rows of weekly data for the years 2010 to 2018. However, I keep getting Value error and Type Error as shown in the code and my screenshot below:

```
from pandas import read_csv
from pandas import datetime
from matplotlib import pyplot

def parser(x):
    return datetime.strptime(x, '%d-%m-%Y')

series = read_csv('testdatafortimeseries.csv', header=0, nrows=215, parse_dates=[0], index_col=0, squeeze=True, date_parser=parser)
print(series.head())
#series.plot()
```

[image: myError]
I am new to learning time series and was only trying to implement an example that used only 36 rows of data. I have tried leaving the dates as 4-Oct-2010 but still no difference. This is what my excel sheet looks like if this helps to identify the problem:
[image: myExcelSheet]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
data = pd.read_csv('DatesExample.csv')
data.head() 
data.Date = pd.to_datetime(data.Date)
data.head()
```

[image]